# Displaying pdf Within iframe in Teams Client

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a teams app, which has an embedded iframe. The iframe link points to an outside server which sends back a pdf as response. But with the teams client app always displays a blank screen within the iframe. When I try calling the same link from iframe embedded inside an html and load that html in a browser, I can see the pdf properly.
The client logs don't show any error message.

Could you tell me what could be going wrong?

Comment: Cross site origin http headers, probably

Comment: @MarcusMüller But the same thing is working from within the browser.

Comment: As said, headers set by teams that restrict cross-site origin elements.

Comment: Could you please check these Prerequisites for building tabs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I visited the microsoft prereqisite that was help ful
I implemented the said header in my web app using below link example
http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2012/12/tomcat-7-custom-valve.html

Hope this will hep you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Marcus Müller  i tried seeting the header Content-Security-Policy and X-Frame-Options suggested by Meghana-MSFT  . But this is still now working ,could you please  tell me what additional i need to restrict cross-site