# Problem rendering pdf; Error: Plugin not loaded since the frame is sandboxed

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to load pdf within an iframe of a teams app. Earlier I had problems receiving the correct response from the server. I posted the  [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76108390/21742643) and after changing the configuration as per the pre-requisites suggested by @Meghana-MSFT in the comment, now I am able to get the response at the client end. I can even download the pdf correctly from teams app.
However,the iframe within which the pdf is supposed to render is still blank. I am getting the following error message:

> Failed to load '' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.

Could you please help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Plugins that cannot be secured are disabled in sandboxed browsing contexts because they might not honor the restrictions imposed by the sandbox (e.g. they might allow scripting even when scripting in the sandbox is disabled). User agents should convey the danger of overriding the sandbox to the user if an option to do so is provided.

Comment: The possible way to get this working is to remove the sandbox value from Content Security Policy. Because there is no possible value to enable plugins. For more info, please refer: https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2015/07/securing-iframe-sandbox-attribute/

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT  now i m getting below error "Failed to load 'blob:https://xxx.xxx.com/3b488fe4-aebd-451c-b2e0-b5a1c1328f06' as a plugin. when i check in web app it return the html response to render pdf using <embed > tag for blob req.there might be some additional restrictions or security settings imposed by the Teams app

Comment: failed to load 'blob:<URL>' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.'  is the error mesage now i do not have any sanbox attribute in teams iframe and i have nessary cors added in web app response.

Comment: Did you remove the sandbox value from CSP? Additionally, could you please refer this: https://content-security-policy.com/